# OpenGL: Execution Flow of QApplication

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, graphics

I am trying to trace the path of execution in some C++ OpenGL starter code but the main method does almost nothing more than this:

```
QApplication app(argc, argv);
MainWindow main_window;
main_window.resize(QSize(width, height));
main_window.show();
return app.exec();
```

These are the .h and .cpp files:

```
GLShape.h    GLTransformStack.h  main.cpp         Matrix4x4.h
GLState.cpp  GLWidget.cpp        MainWindow.h
GLState.h    GLWidget.h          Matrix3x3.h
```

It seems fairly obvious what the all of the various functionalities are, but I can't find where anything is being called/instantiated. I suspect this is being done behind the scenes by `QApplication`.

Is there a standard flow of execution for `QApplication` relative to these files?

In particular, I want to create an animation organized as a tree of shapes. To do this, I am trying to add a class PivotGroup that holds groups of shapes all associated with with a point of rotation. Each PivotGroup has vector of PivotGroup children so that a tree can be constructed.

Where is the best place for the code to create the tree? It seems to make sense as a widget, but I can't tell if one or many widgets are being created.

Comment: GLWidget.cpp looks like the obvious candidate to contain the OpenGL rendering loop. Have you looked at it?

Comment: @Dan: Yes. I noted that in the OP (maybe I was not clear). But because I cannot trace the path of execution, I am not sure if one or many widgets are being instantiated. There is a constructor for the GLWidget class and an initialization method, but the actual instantiation during runtime does not seem to be in any of these files.

Comment: Usually when using OpenGL with Qt the GLWidget class would be instantiated in the constructor of the MainWindow class both of which are inheriting from a Qt class.

Comment: @user3256930: Sweet Jebus! How did I miss that? I thought `MainWindow` was  was the likely candidate, missed it somehow, and then created a conspiracy theory about `QApplication`. :-) Many thanks for replying. If you want the credit, move your comment to an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually when using OpenGL with Qt the GLWidget class would be instantiated in the constructor of the MainWindow class both of which are inheriting from a Qt class. You can also add additional widgets to the MainWindow there.